# Удаление Activity из бэкстека

Tags: java, android, activity

Есть приложения в котором есть `StartActivity` в котором загружается данные с сервера. После данные передаются в  `MainActivity` где данные обрабатываются и выводится на экран.

Нужно, чтобы после запроса `StartActivity` был уничтожен. Но при щелчке назад в `MainActivity` приложения возвращается назад где просто выводится лейаут `StartActivity`.

Нужно сделать так, чтобы после передачи данных `StartActivity` был уничтожен. Как можно реализовать или есть альтернативы?

Comment: Система сама его уничтожит, когда посчитает нужным, вам нет никакой надобности брать этот труд на себя. Опишите подробнее, какую именно проблему Вы пытаетесь решить принудительным удалением активити, чтобы при нажатии "назад" на нее не возвращаться или др?

Comment: @pavlofff Приставьте приложения в котором первый Выходит StartActivity в котором есть прогресс бар и он загружает данные и передает в MainActivity. Проблема в том что при нажатии кнопки назад он возвращается назад в StartActivity что для меня недопустимо

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Вся проблема в том, что `StartActivity` остается в стеке активностей.

Решается все просто: когда из `StartActivity` вызываете `MainActivity` достаточно после `startActivity()` тупо вызвать `finish()` текущего `StartActivity`, тогда при нажатии кнопки вы не вернетесь назад.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
this.startActivity(intent);
this.finish();
```

Comment: Не думал что все так элементарно Большое спасибо

Answer (score 5):

Нужно очистить стэк, после авторизации:

```
      Intent intent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
      intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
      startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что это сработает... Флаги здесь работают в немного другом направлении: они запускают `MainActivity` всегда в новеньким и не используют старый экземпляр (если он уже есть).

Comment: @Barmaley флаг `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` как раз очищает таск от других активити перед запуском новой. Так что сработает.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, насколько это вам подходит, но вот еще один способ.

Можно использовать метод `finishAffinity(),` который будет закрывать текущий Activity и все родительские Activity. Тем самым, вы на `StartActivity` не попадете.

Работает только в Android 4.1 и выше.

Comment: Полезная штука обязательно учту в будущем) Спасибо